# Why did the chicken cross the road?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, imgur-maze

Seriously, why would the chicken do such a foolish act?

I asked a friend for his insight, he just sent me this:

T̵̻͎̟͕͕̅ͩ̏͊̊ͯ͑͒ͣ̃͊̐ͤ̚͘o̡̞̪͚͎̭ͣͬ͂̓̋̐̅ͯ͆͒̾̒̄̓̀̚q̛̮͔̹̙͉̭͖̮͕͕̞͈̼͕̭̬̯̊̍ͪ̓͆̏ͫ͊ͧ͌̅͌ͧ̚͜6̸̱̯̥̭̻͓͉͍͕͕̗̼̤͒́̿̅̃̅ͩͪ̄͒̍̀͡ͅͅF̵̗̘̠̬̥͕͈̠͓̭̯̹͌ͨ͂̔ͫ̃̑ͤ̂̄͛ͪ̃̚̚ͅͅͅͅ

What does the message from my friend mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following on from [rhsquared](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/77567/5373):

> "Escaped goats Enrage Northern Virgina" gives EgENV. Using this as an imgur code gives the following image:
>
>  [image]
>
>  And the text is **fpmy sdl wirdyopmd upi fpmy esmy yjr smdert yp**

Now to decipher that:

> Shift your fingers one letter to the left on the (QWERTY) keyboard, and the text becomes:
>
>  **don't ask questions you don't want the answer to**

Could that be the final answer, or is there more to discover?

Comment: That is all, took longer than I thought `xD`

Comment: What about the chicken?

Comment: @deepthought http://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/chicken

Comment: @WELZ at first I thought the link was broken. I see there are four tiny icons in the corner. "no chicken / yes beef" I guess. Is this still part of the puzzle?

Comment: No, this is part of Stack Exchanges "thing"

Comment: My (very simple and easy) puzzle has been solved by Rand and @rhsquared.

Comment: @WELZ why did the chicken cross the road? => rot13(qba'g nfx dhrfgvbaf lbh qba'g jnag gur nafjre gb)... okay :-D

Answer (score 7):

Partial:

> The tag imgur-maze and the text I think I can read (horizontally), Toq6F lead to an imgur image [image]